# Share page-updating state across files React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

I have a state varible for color in a canvas file

```
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState('#FFFFFF');
```

and I want to access it from a sidebar to put a colour picker in it. Is there a way I can set the variable from another file and have it update on the screen like a normal state variable? Thanks.

Comment: Lift state up to the parent component, or use a Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions and I would say that it depends on your component tree (i.e. how is your application structured).

If your Sidebar and Canvas component have a `shared parent component` (i.e. a component that has Sidebar and Canvas as its children) then the easiest way would probably be to use a concept called `lifting state up` whereby you move the state logic to that *shared* parent component that passes state down to its children via props. Read more about lifting state up in the [official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

An alternative approach is to work with React Context, which is already built-in in the library. This requires more set-up so I would suggest starting with lifting state-up if possible. Read more about Context [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

There are also other solutions such as working with state management libraries (e.g. Redux, Jotai,...) but they are too complicated for this simple use case.