# Share state between separated react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm a new react user, and I'm trying to get a value in Component B from the component A function. I don't know if it is possible to get the value in a simple way as presented here. My code in B is similar to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class B extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            value: 0
        }
    }

    setValue = async(newValue) => {
        this.setState({value: newValue})
    }

    getValue = async() => {
        return this.state.value
    }

    render() {
     return(
       <div className = "flex justify-center">
                <div className = "w-1/2 flex flex-col pb-12">
                    <form onSubmit={(event) => {
                        event.preventDefault()
                        const value = this.value.value
                        this.setValue(value)
                    }}>

                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control mb-1"
                            placeholder="New Value"
                            ref={(input) => this.value= input} />

                        <input type="submit"
                            className="bbtn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm"
                            value="Set Value" />
                    </form> 
                </div>  
            </div>
    )}
} export default B
```

And what I'm trying to do in the A component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './B'

class A extends Component { 

    getValue = async() => {
        const valueInB = B.getValue()
        console.log("Value in B is: ", valueInB);
    }

    render(){
        return(
             <form onSubmit={(event) => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    this.getValue()
                }}>

                    <input type="submit"
                        className="bbtn btn-block btn-success btn-sm"
                        value="Get Value" />
                </form>
        )
    }

} export default A
```

I know the code in getValue() function is wrong but it is a way to show the value I want to get in A component.

Comment: Does this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376801/share-page-updating-state-across-files-react/73387577#73387577) answers your question?

Comment: Your methods need not be `async`.

Comment: You have to use redux or any state library you can't do like this in react.

Comment: you can try using react context or moving the state to a common parent component

Comment: Thank you all. I'm gonna try using redux because I think it is the best option. Regarding @nullptr answer, I've already tried to use one component, and it works, but it is mandatory to use two different components because I need two different pages and share the state between them, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To provide the best answer here we need to consider the relationship between both components.

For instance, if both components are ultimately rendered by a single parent component, then a simple and convenient way to manage this would be to simply move the `state` to the parent and pass it as props to the child components along with the `setState` method or dedicated functions to handle the relevant logic.

**Example:**

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
            value: 0
        }
    }

   return (
      <A state={this.state} setState={this.setState} />
      <B state={this.state} setState={this.setState} />
   )
}
```

However, if that is not the case and the relationship between them is more complex,
then you likely need to manage some global state.
This can be achieved via React's built-in [Context Api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or via third party state managment libraries such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [xState](https://xstate.js.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer . In my case, I have two different pages, so each component is rendered in its context. I think that the best option is using Redux or xState. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome! I would further suggest to make use of the `Context API` if possible. This is both due to it being "built-in" and not requiring importing any additional libraries (remember, this ultimately affects the bundle size), and also due to some of them (such as `Redux`) being very opinionated and generally more complex then `Context`. These libraries are intended more for larger-scale projects, so see if they are really necessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I will try first with Context!

Answer (score 0):

The Context API is the simplest solution as it is part of React itself.

1. Store the shared data & its mutator methods in the state of the topmost component.
2. In the topmost component render the state through a `Provider`.
3. In the components, where this shared data is needed, render a `Subscriber`, & access/modify the data.

This [tutorial](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/react-hooks-guide/) is very helpful, as it describes the process with both class based & function components with examples.